# Оповещение об обновлении игры

Tags: unity3d

Я хочу чтобы когда игрок заходил игра проверяла есть ли обновления, и если есть то игра говорила что надо обновить игру

Comment: а  как то а? я не знаю

Comment: Так и мы не знаем как у вас устроен код:) вы ведь разрабочик игры, вам видней =)

Comment: я искал в интернете как это сделать но не нашёл

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно загрузить PHP скрипт на хостинг с поддержкой PHP. В нём обрабатывать запрос с приложения.

Присмотритесь к классу `WWWForm`, который создан для таких запросов.

Для обращения к серверу потребуется только ссылка на PHP скрипт.

Когда придет информация о последней версии, сравните с текущей.

Не забывайте обновлять информацию на сервере.

Comment: а чё такое php скрипт?

Comment: @АртёмОстапов, php - язык.